# Modifying a .bat script to add a bit of text of my choosing to the output

Tags: batch-file

I posted a question for part of the code further down and got brilliant response which helped me solve my problem. There is a bit of a debate about the validity of the code below but for the moment it works for me and I will look into the concerns in my free time.

```
@echo off
>nul find "var Want_spring_aid_file_update = 1;" "input.txt" && (
  >>output.txt (
 for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ( 'findstr /C:var Front_spring_aid_file = ^"part_name1^"; "input.txt"') do echo %%A
)
)
```

The problem I needed to solve with this code was basically to probe a text file for the presence of a string and based on the result to grab or not a string between double quotes from a specific line of the same text file and drop it in a new text file. Now, as the title explains, I would like to add a bit of text of my choosing to the output.

Basically say I have the following code in a my input text file:

```
var Want_spring_aid_file_update = 1;
var Front_spring_aid_file = "part_name1";
var Rear_spring_aid_file = "part_name2";
```

My current script currently checks if the string in the first line is present and if it is it will probe the second line and grab the string between `""` and drop it in a new text file.

How can I add a bit of text of my choosing to it on the same line? So if it outputs `part_name1` how can I add `The model was updated with part` to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon this and your previous related question, how does the following work for you?

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FI=input.txt"
Set "VM=var Want_spring_aid_file_update "
Set "FM=var Front_spring_aid_file "
Set "SM=var Rear_spring_aid_file "
Set "FO=output.txt"
Set "SO=The model was updated with part"

For /F "Tokens=2Delims==;" %%A In (
    'Find /I "%VM%"^<"%FI%"') Do Set/A VD=%%~A 2>Nul
If Not "%VD%"=="1" Exit/B

>"%FO%" (   For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In (
        'FindStr/ILC:"%FM%" /C:"%SM%" "%FI%" 2^>Nul') Do Echo %SO% %%A)
```

It retrieves the two values you required, only if the value of `Want_spring_aid_file_update` is **`1`**.

**[Edit]** - *(tested Win7)*
Here is the entire content of my `input.txt`:

```
// commented line only
var Want_spring_aid_file_update = 1;
var Front_spring_aid_file = "part_name1";
var Mid_spring_aid_file = "part_name1.5";
var Rear_spring_aId_file = "part_name2";
```

And `output.txt`:

```
The model was updated with part part_name1
The model was updated with part part_name2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I have tried the script and it works but there is a small bug somewhere in there that causes it to output the same thing twice. So instead of outputting "The model was updated with part 'part_name1'" and "The model was updated with part 'part_name2'" it outputs the first item twice. I have tried looking into it myself but I am not sure how the functions work. I have been basically doing batch scripting for two days lol. I will keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: I have tested the script and it works perfectly in my environment. _I have updated the answer with copies of my `input.txt` and `output.txt` files._

Comment: Apologies, I tested this on my personal laptop at home and it worked like a charm. Then I found a small mistake in my work input file that was causing the anomaly. Brilliant stuff mate. If I could bother you I have a couple of questions about the script just to make sure I understand it down to the very last character. In the string `'Find /I "%VM%"^<"%FI%"'` what do `^<` do? Also that string finds the line that has the string stored in `%VM%` but then the command before it splits the line into tokens and takes the second token which in this case is `1` Am I right. Next question in next com.

Comment: The second question is in the string `Do Set/A VD=%%~A 2>Nul` what does `2>Nul` do? I am guessing that `2^>Nul` in `FindStr/ILC:"%FM%" /C:"%SM%" "%FI%" 2^>Nul` does the same thing as in the previous string. The last small thing is `/ILC:` is basically a construction of multiple switches, right?